# How can I create an H.264 encoded movie from a set of images in c#?

Tags: c#, video-encoding, h.264

I have been doing a lot of searching today for C# libraries which will allow me to create H.264 encoded video files. Does anyone know if any such libraries or 3rd party components exist?

Comment: Just curious, what software are you writing that requires H.264 encoding?

Comment: Basically I need the ability to combine a set of radar images into a 'flip-book' style animation on-the-fly from a web server. I am currently using SWFMill to create a flash movie, but I need to be able to support H.264 now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [ffmpeg](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-doc.html). I suggest to run a ffmpeg process directly, like in this sample: http://jasonjano.wordpress.com/2010/02/09/a-simple-c-wrapper-for-ffmpeg/

While the sample doesn't deal with the operation you need, I suggest to adapt it to your needs.

Comment: Thanks. This is the closet thing to an answer here.

Comment: yes, I also struggled figuring out what to use in a different scenario. Once I got my mind set on modifying the sample to support the operations that I needed, it all went nicely for me.

Comment: @eglasius: Is there a way to get a progress of the current ffmpeg process action so I can notify user asynchronously with each progress change?

Answer (score 0):

[ffmpeg-sharp](http://code.google.com/p/ffmpeg-sharp/) is probably a good starting point.

Comment: It is too new of a project. They currently have no support for video encoding. Thanks though.