# how to get default thumbnails of a video

Tags: c#, facebook, video

i want all the thumbnails of the video when someone pastes a link on my site
like one happening in facebook.dat gives the option to select the thumbnail from its actual thumbnails.

Answer (score 1):

Use some component that allows you to extract the frames, and **obtain a frame each x seconds**.

Personally I don't know of one in c#, specially if its a web application (you didn't mention).

What I use for video related operations is **ffmpeg**, like I mentioned in this answer to an unrelated question: [how can I create an H-264 encoded movie from a set of images in c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2509648/how-can-i-create-an-h-264-encoded-movie-from-a-set-of-images-in-c/2999650#2999650) (which happens to be almost the opposite of what you need).