# Is there a set of working P/Invoke declarations for FFMpeg, libavutil, libavformat and libavcodec in .NET?

Tags: .net, ffmpeg, libavcodec, libavformat

I'm currently looking to access libavutil, libavformat and libavcodec (all part of FFMpeg) from .NET.

Currently, I'm getting the [libraries from the automated builds of the shared FFMpeg package](http://ffmpeg.arrozcru.org/autobuilds/) performed every night for Windows 32-bit.

I am also using the code from the [ffmpeg-sharp project](http://code.google.com/p/ffmpeg-sharp/).  In that project, I have removed a number of classes that were not compiling (they are wrapper classes not the P/Invoke declarations).

The code compiles fine, but I am running into a few issues.

First, it appears that the build of av*.dll uses the [cdecl calling convention](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions#cdecl), as I was receiving a number of `PInvokeStackImbalanceException` when trying to call [`av_open_input_file`](http://cekirdek.uludag.org.tr/~ismail/ffmpeg-docs/avformat_8h.html#9baec525f6e67ca07ce289a55cc60589).  This was easy enough to change to get it to work right.  The [`AVFormatContext`](http://cekirdek.uludag.org.tr/~ismail/ffmpeg-docs/structAVFormatContext.html) structure is populated.

After that, I want to call [`av_find_stream_info`](http://cekirdek.uludag.org.tr/~ismail/ffmpeg-docs/avformat_8h.html#db71739e723184582491854960a5cb61) to get information about the streams in the file.  However, when calling that with the `AVFormatContext` retrieved from the call to `av_open_input_file`, an [`AccessViolationException`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.accessviolationexception.aspx) is thrown indicating that I am trying to read or write from protected memory.

Has anyone used P/Invoke to access the libavutil, libavformat and libavcodec dll libraries through P/Invoke and have gotten it to work?

I should mention that working with the command-line version of FFMpeg, while a solution, is not a viable solution in this case, access needs to occur through the libraries.  The reason for this is that I'd have to thrash the disk way too much to do what I need to do (I have to do a frame-by-frame analysis of some very high definition video) and I want to avoid the disk as much as possible.

Comment: Re: disk thrashing concerns, I just achieved some success with capturing ffmpeg output--yes content, not metadata--via the stdout pipe. If this can fit your scenario, there's no file and it doesn't hit the disk.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what I figured out - namely, a good amount of the P/Invoke declarations in the ffmpeg-sharp project are incorrect.  There are a good number of places where they use structures in the declaration which are marshaled back, but subsequently, have to be passed to deallocation routines later.

Because the pointer has been lost as part of the marshaling, this is what was causing the [`AccessViolationException`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.accessviolationexception.aspx) to be thrown when trying to pass that stucture to other methods that are accepting a valid pointer (like a handle in Windows).  Instead of treating them as opaque (as they should, like Windows APIs do) they marshal the structures back and lose the pointer in the process.

The solution is to change their API declarations to take/return an [`IntPtr`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.intptr%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) and perform marshaling of the structures as needed, not to include them in the P/Invoke declarations.

Comment: I'm now looking for a simple .NET wrapper that should expose one global Convert method and should use ffmpeg. I also need it to raise an event each time its progress changes, so I can run it asynchronously and notify user with a percentage.

Answer (score 1):

See [Auto Generated FFmpeg wrapper for C#/.NET and Mono](https://github.com/Ruslan-B/FFmpeg.AutoGen/).

Answer (score 0):

I've steered clear from any of those libraries/projects. All info I found at the time pointed to those breaking too easily with new versions and/or just being too out of date.

What I did is was run the ffmpeg process directly, as I mentioned on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2509648/how-can-i-create-an-h-264-encoded-movie-from-a-set-of-images-in-c/2999650#2999650), by modifying a sample in a blog post I link there. To this date we've not had trouble with it :)

If the above doesn't work for your scenario, good luck.

Comment: I modified the question, but I should mention that using the command-line is not an option.  I'd have to thrash the disk way too much to do what I need to do (I have to do a frame-by-frame analysis of some very high definition video) and I want to avoid the disk as much as possible.

Comment: I haven't done it, but you might be able to redirect the output to avoid having to go to the disk to grab it

Comment: I figurd it out, see my answer below.  It's more how ffmpeg-sharp handles P/Invoke.  I'm able to get stream/codec information from files now in memory.

Comment: @CasperOne glad to hear, +1 to your answer & your question.

Answer (score 0):

SharpFFmpeg imports c++ libraries. C++ code is an unmanaged code. It needs pointers to the unmanaged memory. "Marshal" class provides some method to allocate unmanaged memory. For example:

```
    IntPtr buffer = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(buf.Length + FFmpeg.FF_INPUT_BUFFER_PADDING_SIZE); //buf is a byte array
```

Also, if you want to send a managed variable (any C# variable) to the function, you have to marshal (copy) this variable to the unmanaged memory.

```
    for (int i = 0; i < buf.Length; i++)
        Marshal.StructureToPtr(buf[i], buffer + i, true);
```

Now you can send a pointer to the function.

```
    FFmpeg.avcodec_decode_video(codecContextUnmanaged, frame, ref success, buffer, buf.Length);
```

It's possible that you'll need to modify some unmanaged structures. To do this you have to copy structure to a managed memory (Marshal.PtrToStructure method), then modify it, and copy it to an unmanaged memory again.
I was tormented by the same problem a lot. I solved it, but I can't decode video anyway)) I hope my solution will help anybody.