# Error using ffmpeg-Sharp

Tags: c#, ffmpeg

Why does this code throws an **`MarshalDirectiveException`**?
Obs: I am using [ffmpeg-Sharp](http://code.google.com/p/ffmpeg-sharp/)

> Cannot marshal 'return value': Pointers cannot reference marshaled
>   structures.  Use ByRef instead.

```
class Program
{
    unsafe static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        AVCodecContext* ctx = 
                 FFmpeg.avcodec_alloc_context();
    }
}
```

Comment: [There were a number of known problems with the ffmpeg-Sharp project](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3790518/50776), so many that I personally abandoned it.  [There's been a major commit on January 5, 2012](http://code.google.com/p/ffmpeg-sharp/source/detail?r=24) but it doesn't look to address the problems that I've found, frankly.

Comment: I've found that a handful of these projects are flawed... It'd be very helpfull if it worked right...

Comment: do you have any sugestions for me?